# Extending Continuous Basis

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

It is given $(k-d)$ continuous vector-valued functions $K_1,\dots,K_{k-d}:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^k$, with $d\leq k$. Suppose that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$, the set ${\cal K}=\{K_1(x),\dots,K_{k-d}(x)\}$ is linear independent.

I'd like to add $d$ continuous vector-valued functions $B_1,\dots,B_d:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^k$ such that the set ${\cal B}=\{K_1(x),\dots,K_{k-d}(x),B_1(x),\dots,B_d(x) \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^k$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Note that, for FIXED $x_0$ we can take $d$-vectors from the standard basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_k\}$, namely by $f_1,\dots,f_d$ such that $\{K_1(x_0),\dots,K_{k-d}(x_0),f_1,\dots,f_d\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^k$. However, the problem here is this choice depends on $x_0$, and I worried about the continuity. Can anyone help me? Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: Quick remark on a related problem: the case of $\mathcal{C}^k$ functions, for $k\geq 1$, is studied in numerical analysis; see for instance http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895479897330182. I looked at that paper, and unfortunately it only deals with $k\geq 1$; nevertheless, it might be a useful reference.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoPoloni. I'll go to the given link

Comment: Maybe it's not obvious at first sight why that paper is related to the problem: the reason is that, if $K=USV^T$ is the SVD of a $n\times m$ matrix $K$ with $n>m$, then the first $m$ columns of $U$ are a basis for the range of $K$ and the rest of its columns complete it to a basis. So if you can compute a continuous SVD, you can also complete a basis.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoPoloni. I'll read the paper carefully

Comment: By the way @FedericoPoloni, where did you find the fact that  if $K=USV^T$ is the SVD of a n×m matrix $K$ with n>m, then the first m columns of U are a basis for the range of $K$ and the rest of its columns complete it to a basis? I didn't find in the paper

Comment: It's not in the paper, but it is a known fact from linear algebra that is not excessively hard to prove. Sorry if I didn't state it in the previous comment. You can verify directly from $K=USV^T$ and the fact that $S$ has $S_{ii}=0$ for $i>m$ that $\operatorname{range}(K)$ is the span of the first columns of $U$; then, $U$ is orthogonal, so its columns form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructing a continuous matrix valued function](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/155275/constructing-a-continuous-matrix-valued-function)

Answer (score 3):

Step 1 in the previous answer is very doubtful, as one needs to "trivialize" the family of $(k-d)$-planes.

The truth is that there is no **functorial** way to extend a $(k-d)$-frame to a $k$-basis if $d>1$. In the OP's problem, an extension **does** exist, solely due to the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, hence any vector bundle over $\mathbb{R}$ is trivial. (But there is no "standard" way to trivialize it.) To illustrate the problem, consider $S^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $k=3$. The Gauss map $S^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is a continuous family of $1$-frames, but it does **not** extend to a family of bases: the tangent bundle of $S^2$ is nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, so do you mean that It is impossible to construct what I want above?

Comment: Well, as I said, such a thing **exists**, just because your source is contractible. You can probably construct it locally and patch together, but there's no nice **formula** for that (except the case of codimension $1$). In the learned language, the $O(d)$-fibration $O(k)\to V(k,k-d)$ has no continuous sections.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I'll think again about this

Comment: By the way @Alex, what do you mean with "my source is contractible"? If I don't need the closed formula, how can we prove that such extension exists?

Comment: You have a trivial $k$-bundle over $\mathbb{R}$ and a (also trivial) $(k-d)$-subbundle, say, $\xi$; extending the frames means trivializing the orthogonal complement $\xi^\perp$. (As usual, all structure groups can be reduced to the orthogonal ones.) Well, the base being contractible, **any** vector bundle is trivial, hence can be trivialized. (This is homotopy theory, but this works in the smooth settings, too.) In general, you can only claim that $\xi^\perp$ is what is called _stably trivial_; as the example of $S^2$ shows, this does not always imply the triviality.

Comment: I am not familiar with homotopy theory. Could you explain using fundamental real analysis please?

Comment: No, sorry, partition of unity won't work. I think you can do analysis. You have a principal $O(d)$-bundle over $\mathbb{R}$, and you want to construct a continuous section. As usual, there is a maximal interval over which such a section exists. Prove that it can be made closed (probably, care is needed to avoid oscillation at the ends) and then, locally again, extend beyond the endpoints. But I really never thought about this analytically; this is just elementary obstruction theory.

Comment: OK @Alex. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1.  We can assume $d=1$ and then proceed by induction.                         2. We can use Gram-Schmidt to assume that the basis is orthonormal (for, e.g., the standard scalar product).  This is done explicitly and doesn't destroy continuity.   3.  We then take the unique unit vector in dependence on $x$ which is orthogonal to this basis (the apparent non-uniqueness is avoided by imposing an orientation condition to choose between the two possibilities). Again this dependence will be continuous.

Comment: Thanks @alpha your suggestions. What I wonder is about your third step. How will we take that vector without destroying the continuity?

Comment: In the jump from dimension $2$ to $3$ you would use the vector product.  There is a concept of such a vector product in dimension $n$---in this case you take the product of $n-1$ vectors (see, for example, "Calculus on manifolds" by Spivak).

Comment: OK, thanks for your helps @alpha. I'll look that book